# Canonical Function "EntityFunctions.TruncateTime" does not exist in MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm trying to run this query:

```
DateTime DDate=DateTime.Today; //Today's date without Time
var v= db.measurements.Where(m => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(m.InDate) == DDate);
```

It just returns objects where those two dates are equal, ignoring the time part.

But I receive:

{"FUNCTION [database].TruncateTime does not exist"}

StackTrace:

```
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

I'm using:

- C# Visual Studio 2010
- EntityFramework 4 database first
- NetFramework 4
- MYSQL Server 5.6

The version of MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entity is 6.6.5.0

[TruncateTime is supported by MySQL.](http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-canonical-functions.html)

[Same thing happened to this person.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752939/entityfunctions-support-in-mysql)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I couldn't resolve it, so I just created a Function named "TruncateTime" in the database.

```
Create FUNCTION TruncateTime(dateValue DateTime) RETURNS date
return Date(dateValue);
```

And it works, but I don't like it.

These people did similar things:

[Alternative to EntityFunctions.AddSeconds for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951714/alternative-to-entityfunctions-addseconds-for-mysql)

[CurrentUtcDateTime does not exist - Entity Framework and MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016765/currentutcdatetime-does-not-exist-entity-framework-and-mysql)

So now I think that might be unnecessary and I can just call it directly from the database and still get entities, something like this:

```
var x = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Measurement>(@"SELECT field1,field2
FROM   Measurements
WHERE  Date(InDate) = {0}", DDate);
```

And that's all.

Comment: I never realized it is not there in database. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The approach in [A Torres' response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731414/474270) works, but it felt a bit hacky for me, so I have found another approach (This works for EF6, for EF5 a similar approach exists, but I can't test it):

1. Create class DatabaseFunctions and add the following code to it:

   ```
   [Function(FunctionType.BuiltInFunction, "Date")]
   public static DateTime? Date(DateTime? dateValue) 
       => Function.CallNotSupported<DateTime>();
   ```
2. Add the following line to OnModelCreating in your DbContext

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
       modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention<DatabaseFunctions>())
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Use DatabaseFunctions.Date instead of EntityFunctions.TruncateTime.

Comment: This should be the answer. The query optimizer won't be able to optimize any query with a custom function so built in functions should be used

Comment: I'm in a situation where A Torres's answer won't work in my case. This answer looks extremely promising, but seems incomplete or incorrect. For instance, my EDI doesn't understand FunctionConvention. Can you explain your code a bit more completely?

Comment: @Goose - I'm not sure what EDI means, but if it doesn't understand FunctionConvention it looks like you are using a very old version of Entity Framework. Do you know which version are you using?

Comment: "Integrated Development Environment". I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 so I assume it's pretty recent.

Comment: Oh, you ment IDE.
Visual Studio version is not necessarily connected to the version of Entity Framework you are using.

Anyway, make sure you have a reference to Entity Framework 6 and that you added "using EntityFramework.Functions" to the top of your file (You might also need to add reference to EntityFramework.Functions, I don't remember for sure).

Answer (score 0):

no need i delete it (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime) work with me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).