# C# linq how to search data between two date

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I am working on Windows base application I want search details between two date 
so am using linq query for that.

My query is:

```
mealsdbEntities objEntity = new mealsdbEntities();
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");

DateTime OrderFromDate = DateTime.Parse(dtOrderFDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
DateTime OrderToDate = DateTime.Parse(dtOrderToDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
DateTime DelFromDate = DateTime.Parse(dtOrderDelFDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
DateTime DelToDate = DateTime.Parse(dtOrderDelTDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

var OrderList = (from ol in objEntity.orders
                 join cust_Con in objEntity.customermasters 
                      on ol.customer_id equals cust_Con.id
                 join cust_Cont in objEntity.customercontacts 
                      on ol.customer_id equals cust_Cont.customer_id
                 join oDish in objEntity.orderdishes 
                      on ol.id equals oDish.order_id
                 where cust_Con.company_name.Contains("" + txt_Cust_name.Text + "") 
                       && (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(OrderFromDate) == OrderFromDate) 
                       //>= OrderFromDate) && (ol.createdon <= OrderToDate)) 
                       //&& (ol.deliverydate >= DelFromDate && ol.deliverydate <= DelToDate)
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = ol.id,
                     Title = ol.title,
                     Name = cust_Con.company_name,
                     Phone = cust_Cont.contact_phone,
                     // Item = disgcateg.dish_name,
                     DeliveryDate = ol.deliverydate,
                     DeliveryTime = ol.deliverytime,
                     Amount = ol.orderamount,
                     Status = ol.status
                 }).ToList();
```

but I am getting an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Can anyone kindly tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: How do you expect this to be true _(EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(OrderFromDate) == OrderFromDate)_ if OrderFromDate is not exactly at midnight? Anyway, what is the innerexception?

Comment: @Steve System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");
            DateTime OrderFromDate = DateTime.Parse(dtOrderFDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            DateTime OrderToDate = DateTime.Parse(dtOrderToDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            DateTime DelFromDate = DateTime.Parse(dtOrderDelFDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            DateTime DelToDate = DateTime.Parse(dtOrderDelTDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

Comment: @Steve i already edit my code

Comment: "See the inner exception for details." - so did you? What were the details? Please put them in your question.

Comment: (And why are you formatting a value just to parse it again? That's a very error-prone approach.)

Comment: This `TruncateTime` function never works for me

Comment: Can you please show us the table definition for the mysql tables (in particular the types of each of the columns)?

Comment: @jon skeet what you say ? can u explain me.

Comment: I'm saying that the outer exception has already told you what you should do next: look at the inner exception. (I'm also saying that you're currently formatting a date value as a string only to parse it again, and that's a really bad idea. I don't know why you're doing that.)

Comment: @jon skeet so can u tell me what is the good idea?

Comment: @mjwills id int(11)
customer_id int(11)
title varchar(50)
deliverydate datetime
deliverytime time
orderamount decimal(10,0)
status int(11)
createdon datetime
createdby int(11)
editedon datetime
editedby int(11)

Comment: I give up - I don't know how many different ways I can say "look at the inner exception".

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714022/canonical-function-entityfunctions-truncatetime-does-not-exist-in-mysql help?

Comment: If a pop up box comes up.  Press Copy exception to clipboard.  Then open up notepad and paste results into notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq lambda

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2017, 12, 31);

//this includes the last day
var endDatePlus = endDate.AddDays(1);

.Where(obj => obj.StartDate >= startDate && obj.EndDate < endDatePlus).ToList();
```

Comment: Given that we don't know what the OP's actual error is, it's far from clear that this will help.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
var OrderList = (from ol in objEntity.orders
                 join cust_Con in objEntity.customermasters 
                 on ol.customer_id equals cust_Con.id
                 join cust_Cont in objEntity.customercontacts 
                 on ol.customer_id equals cust_Cont.customer_id
                 join oDish in objEntity.orderdishes 
                 on ol.id equals oDish.order_id
                 where cust_Con.company_name.Contains("" + txt_Cust_name.Text + "") 
                 && (OrderFromDate.Date == OrderFromDate.Date) 
                 //>= OrderFromDate) && (ol.createdon <= OrderToDate)) 
                 //&& (ol.deliverydate >= DelFromDate && ol.deliverydate <= DelToDate)
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = ol.id,
                     Title = ol.title,
                     Name = cust_Con.company_name,
                     Phone = cust_Cont.contact_phone,
                     // Item = disgcateg.dish_name,
                     DeliveryDate = ol.deliverydate,
                     DeliveryTime = ol.deliverytime,
                     Amount = ol.orderamount,
                     Status = ol.status
                 }).ToList();
```